# How to code foreign chars on website

Tags: internationalization

How can I code foreign alpha chars in English website, e.g.; Russian, German, etc.
(Don't want to have to code in hex strings)

Answer (score 2):

A good option is to use utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) and locales.  Languages like Java, C#, and Python support it.

Comment: And Perl, and Ruby, and basically every modern language out there. ;)